# Wait for another batch file to finish the process and process another batch file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

Is it possible to wait first for the first batch file to process and then process another batch file? if i run multiple batch file at the same time i got an error "Another instance of the application is already running. Please close the application dialog before using any other program." when calling the program.exe multiple times at the same time.

This is what i tried

```
@echo off
START /Wait cmd.exe /K "C:\Users\Folder\Pictures\batchFile\Encrypt\encrypt.bat"
```

and here's the command of the encrypt file to encrypt the pdf file:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Folder\Program.exe" PROTECT "C:\Users\Folder\Pictures\test1.pdf" /OUTPUT "C:\Users\Folder\Pictures\d"
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Comment: Call the second batch file at the end of the first.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following code for executing your batch files one by one.

```
System.Diagnostics.Process SysDiag = null;

SysDiag = Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo(yourBatchFilePath));

while (SysDiag.HasExited == false)
{}
```

Comment: This is not batch-file related.